# jQuery on click move a div after() the parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-after

In the following code, how can I move the `<div class="move">I was moved to the parent.</div>` after the parent of the element I click, when I click `Add New`.

I have everything right, but I cannot do the part where I need to move it `after()` the parent.

Can you please help?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Side bar poll thingy</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/site/scripts/jQueryCore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.add').click(function() {
    $("#container").find('.flag, .edit, .delete').remove();
    $(this).parent("div").after(".move");

    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div class="h1" data-id="1">Teachers <span class="add" data-id="US01">Add New</span></div>
    <div class="h2" data-id="2">Who is your favorite Math teacher? <span class="add" data-id="US02">Add New</span></div>
        <br>
    <div class="h1" data-id="8">Restaurants <span class="add" data-id="US10">Add New</span></div>
    <div class="h2" data-id="9">Which is your favourtie restaurant in town? <span class="add" data-id="US20">Add New</span></div>

    <div class="move">I was moved to the parent.</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you mean outside the "container" div right ?

Comment: No. After the `div` that contains the `span class="add"` which was clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/QP3MZ/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.add').click(function () {
        $("#container").find('.flag, .edit, .delete').remove();
        var $move = $('#container .move');
        $(this).parent("div").after($move);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`.after()` doesn't accept selectors, currently you are inserting `.move` string after the selected element. You can use `.insertAfter()` method instead:

```
$(".move").insertAfter(this.parentNode);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RYzpG/

Answer (score 1):

This code should work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.add').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#container").find('.flag, .edit, .delete').remove();
        $('.move').insertAfter($(this).parent());
        //Or (Note we have to pass a jQuery element inside after, if we pass string then it will copy the string instead)
        //$(this).parent('div').after($('.move'));
    });
});
```

Also here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4zsPm/). The reason why yours wasn't working is you are passing a string inside the `.after`, which jQuery would treat as an HTML string. You had to pass a jQuery element or DOM element. See it [here](http://api.jquery.com/after/#after-content-content).